# Контент одного дива поверх другого

Tags: javascript, html, css

Реализовал боковое меню:

```
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 10px;
```

**Проблема** (1): если я хочу, чтобы содержимое страницы сдвигался вместе с меню, то ширина страницы увеличивается. Все логично, но на телефоне это выглядит мягко говоря некрасиво, потому что при увеличении ширины страницы, уменьшается масштаб страницы.

Я убрал сдвиг содержимого вместе с меню и споткнулся об еще одну **проблему** (2): Содержимое страницы (содержимое дива) залазит на боковое меню.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Тоесть не сам див поверх другово, а его контент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только что поигрался с исходным кодом вашей страницы (вы ведь не потрудились выложить код).

К блоку, ответственному за выдвижное меню добавил:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 999999; // можно меньше,главное - чтобы больше, чем у того элемента, "над которым" он должен быть
```

И все заработало как надо (наверное).